# Camel Main to process big file and stop the route and exit from JVM

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a requirement to process the big file using these 2 case
(1) Pull from file directory and push to FTP
(2) Pull from one FTP and push to another FTP

I am creating a java maven dependency project which use camel components to process above use-case of file transfer, so I decided to use org.apache.camel.main.Main class to start my route, but the problem is my program is not getting closed even after file is processed successfully. Somewhere I read that using "System.exit()" would solve the problem but still problem exists.

My code-

```
Main camelMain = new Main();
camelMain.enableHangupSupport();
camelMain.addRouteBuilder(getRouteBuilderLocaltoFTP());
camelMain.run();
```

RouteBuilder

```
public void configure() throws Exception { 
    from(<File-Path>).routeId("local-to-ftp")
    .onCompletion().process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getContext().stop();       
                }
            })
            .toD(<FTP-Path>);
```

Also tried using control-Bus
.toF("controlbus:route?routeId=%s&action=stop&async=true", "local-to-ftp")

But in both the cases, routes are shutting down gracefully not closing the program.

Seek help in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure on the main to shutdown the application after X period of time, or after processing N number of messages. And you can set both of them AFAIR, eg shutdown after 2 minutes, and after 1 message processed.

Just check the methods on `camelMain`. Mind that this requires a recent version of Apache Camel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved it by having separate route for shutdown and calling this shutdown route from main route and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Various ways of Graceful Shutdown is documented [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/graceful-shutdown.html). You can try this code to shutdown a particular route

```
camelContext.getRouteController().stopRoute("routeId");
camelContext.removeRoute("routeId");
```